# Mysql calculate rank based on level DESC and experience DESC

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have a table named hiscores where I want to search a nickname of one user and get his current rank, since the rank rown doesn't exist because the ranks are organized by lvl DESC and then by Experience , so I want a sql query where I search the name of that
"player1" and it returs me rank 2. or input healdeal and get rank 1

```
 Table =  hiscores

id - nickname- lvl - experience

1   - healdeal - 99    - 1000

2   - philip   - 98    - 595

3   - Player1  - 98    - 620

4   - Mindblow - 52    - 35
```

I have tried the following

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) + 1) AS rank FROM hiscores WHERE lvl >(SELECT lvl FROM hiscores WHERE nickname="player1")
```

Comment: Is this MySQL or MS-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is MySQL, this will work:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 Rank, 
h.* 
from hiscores h, 
(SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
order by level desc, experience desc
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ace02/3)

If this is MS SQL Server 2005 onwards, you can directly use window functions, like so:

```
select *, rank() over (order by level desc, experience desc) Rank
from hiscores
```

In either case, if you want to filter by the nickname, you can put the above expression into a subquery and filter that by the nickname i.e.

```
select * from
(<ranking expression from above>) rankedresults
where nickname = <input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see.  You are trying to calculate the rank.  I think this might do it:

```
select count(*) as rank
from hiscores hs cross join
     (select hs.*
      from hiscores
      where nickname = 'player1'
     ) hs1
where hs.lvl > hs1.lvl or
      hs.lvl = hs1.lvl and hs.experience >= hs1.experience;
```

Actually, if you have ties on both `experience` and `lvl`, then this might be a better rank:

```
select 1 + count(*) as rank
from hiscores hs cross join
     (select hs.*
      from hiscores
      where nickname = 'player1'
     ) hs1
where hs.lvl > hs1.lvl or
      hs.lvl = hs1.lvl and hs.experience > hs1.experience;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL 2005+. You can do this:

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT,nickname VARCHAR(100),lvl INT, experience INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(1 ,'healdeal',99,1000),
(2 ,'philip',98,595),
(3 ,'Player1',98,620),
(4 ,'Mindblow',52,35)
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY lvl DESC,experience DESC) AS rank,
        tbl.*
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.nickname='Player1'
```

**Output**

```
2   3   Player1 98  620
```